# Laravel generate the routes using Route::resource need to add prefix /admin/

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, admin

For example , I have a routes that is for the admin page to manage books, a route is set like this:

```
Route::resource('books','Admin\BookController');
```

It generated few routes for insert / update/ delete etc... automatically

```
/books/create
/books/1/edit
```

The problem is , it is admin page and I would like the link to be

```
/admin/books/create 
/admin/books/1/edit
```

How to specific the resource to be admin one ? it auto have prefix of /admin/ Thanks

Updated:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need prefix for a multiple routes, you should use [route group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#route-groups):

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin'], function()
{
    Route::resource('books','Admin\BookController');
});
```

Or, if you need to use just one controller, you could just do this:

```
Route::resource('/admin/books','Admin\BookController');
```

Comment: thanks , but it show syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting ']'

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've forgot the closing `]`. Fixed now.

Comment: thanks for the quick fix. And if I go to http://localhost:8000/admin/books it show Route [books.edit] not defined.

Comment: You can check for all defined routes with `php artisan route:list` command. If route is in the list, you should check web server configuration.

Comment: yes updated the question, would you mind have a look at the error screen cap? also , I am using the make: auth of the laveral , how to add the /admin/ for those login, register path ? thanks a lot.

Comment: Error says you're using `books.edit` route, but you need to use `admin.books.edit` route in your view now. Look at the `name` column in the route list. These are the names of your routes that you should use in your app.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `route` to

```
Route::resource('admin/books','Admin\BookController');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Alexey's Answer. I'm using Namespace too with group. Below is the example.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix'     => 'admin',
    'namespace'  => 'Admin',
    'middleware' => 'admin.routeNeedsPermission:view-admin-management',
], function() { 
       Route::resource('books','BookController');
});
```

By that way you don't need to write admin in all your routes.